# div always right, all browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser

I just create the next css code for div to be always the right:

```
#button > .right{
  background-position: -268px 1415px;
  height: 180px;
  position: fixed;
  right: -90px;
  top: 40%;
  width: 263px;
 -webkit-transform                : scale(0.23);
 -moz-transform                   : scale(0.23);
 -o-transform                     : scale(0.23);
 -ms-transform                        : scale(0.23);
 transform                        : scale(0.23);
}
```

I try in firefox and this code is good, but when I try in others browsers this is not found.

Any Idea?

pdt: this is the url http://supboat.herokuapp.com/

Edit: This code is fine, the problem was because this div was inside other div with position:relative.

Comment: What other browsers are you talking about. it works for me in Google Chrome, I.E 9.0 and Firefox? Can you be more clear?

Comment: Really ?, in the designer computer this looks really bad, I will attach pictures of the problem.

Comment: Also seems to work fine for me too, but could be a z-index issue as you don't seem to have pplied any z-indexes to your positioned objects

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very easy to solve. Your set `right:-90px;` that means the div is shifted out of the visible screen for 90px. You set the width to 263px and then scale it to 0.23. That is round about 60px (263 * 0.23). That means your div is there, but his left border is about 30 pixel right of your visible viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Just calculate the width of the screen and then update the value of left coordinate of your button.

For Eg:-

```
<button id="right"><button>

<script>
    var x=$(window).width();
    var right=document.getElementById("right");
    right.style.position="absolute";
    right.style.left=x+"px";
</script>
```

x is the total width of the screen and then you have assigned "x" to the left coordinate of your button ... :)